# Number of ways to represent any N as sum of odd numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, integer-partitions

I was solving some basic Math Coding Problem and found that For any number $N$, the number of ways to express $N$ as sum of Odd Numbers is $Fib[N]$ where $Fib$ is Fibonnaci , I don't have a valid proof for this and didnot understand that how this can be solved using recurrences Can someone provide with it ?
If you are not getting it Suppose for N=4 number of ways to write it as sum of Odd Numbers is 3 which is Fibonnaci at $3$

$4=> 1+1+1+1$ 
$4=> 1+3$ 
$4=> 3+1$ 
NOTE-> the composition is ordered $( 1+3)$ and $(3+1)$ are different .
UPD -> I do not claim that I observed it myself but in the problem solution I found it , I asked to just find some valid proof / reason to it

Comment: This is a beautiful observation you found.

Comment: I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006387/representing-a-nonnegative-integer-as-the-ordered-sum-of-odd-numbers/2006393

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say $S(n)$ is the set of ways to write $n$ as a sum of odd numbers.

We can partition this set into two subsets: $A(n)$ and $B(n)$, where $A(n)$ is the set of sums where the last summand is a $1$, and $B(n)$ is the set of all other sums.

Can you see why $A(n)$ has the same size as $S(n-1)$? Can you see why $B(n)$ has the same size as $S(n-2)$?

If you prove this, you find that $|S(n)| = |A(n)| + |B(n)| = |S(n-1)| + |S(n-2)|$, which is the Fibonacci recurrence relation. You can then prove by induction that your sequence is equal to the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Last summand is 1? why is that coming ?

Comment: Example: $S(5) = \{1{+}1{+}1{+}1{+}1, 1{+}1{+}3, 1{+}3{+}1, 3{+}1{+}1, 5\}$, $A(5) = \{1{+}1{+}1{+}1{+}1, 1{+}3{+}1, 3{+}1{+}1\}$, $B(5) = \{1{+}1{+}3, 5\}.$ You can see that A(5) has the same size as S(4) and B(5) has the same size as S(3).

Comment: what does A(5) signify here?

Comment: A(5) is the set of all possible ways to write $5$ as a sum of odd numbers. $A(12)$ is the set of all possible ways to write $12$ as a sum of odd numbers.

Comment: getting you now , Understood the solution , :) will accept your answer later , just finding out new ways to do it as well  like this ogz one

Comment: Thank you @Magma

Comment: Can I clarify your solution a bit? It's elegant. One sees $A(n)=S(n-1)$ as to fix (or can be cut it out) the last summand $1$ and the rest follows the pattern of $S(n-1)$. For $B(n)$, we can replace (in our mind) $n$ to be $n-2$ and nothing is difference between $S(n-2)$ and the (replaced) $B(n)$ and $B(n)=S(n-2)$.

Comment: How does this proof depend on the fact that we’re summing odd numbers? Otherwise this should work for the number of ways to sum to $n$ with even or odd integers.

Comment: @EnricoBorba If odd summands were not required, we would obtain $B(n) = S(n-1)$ instead.

Answer (score 4):

We have from first principles that the number of compositions into odd parts is given by

$$[z^N] \sum_{q\ge 1} \left(\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^q.$$

This simplifies to

$$[z^N] \frac{z/(1-z^2)}{1-z/(1-z^2)}
= [z^N] \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}.$$

Now $$F(z) = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$$ is the OGF of the Fibonacci numbers and we have the claim.

Comment: what is this using first principles  ? I think I dont know this much But I surely want to learn any Resources for understanding ur solution better

Comment: The OGF $z/(1-z^2)$ gives a single odd part so $(z/(1-z^2))^q$ gives a composition into $q$ odd parts. We have $q\ge 1$ parts hence the sum.

Comment: where is it coming from OGF , z and all stuff ? is this linear algebra?

Comment: Learn more at [Wikipedia on the Fibonacci number OGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series).

Comment: Thanks for it :) ,

Comment: Did you mean $\displaystyle [z^N]\left(\sum_{q\ge 1}\left(\dfrac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^q\right)$ to be the coefficient of $z^N$ of the expanded function $\displaystyle \sum_{q\ge 1}\left(\dfrac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^q$? An elegant solution. Though I have a question about the OGF $z/(1-z^2)$ gives a single odd parts as well.

Comment: Here is [Wikipedia on coefficient extractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).